# Black screen when building a custom layout app

Tags: android, flutter

I am learning Flutter and as part of the learning process I would like to build a new app template similar to `MaterialApp`.

I started very simple with a `Container` and a `Row` that will contain the placeholders for the: toolbar, content area, and bottom navigation, but for now, this `Container` contains just three `Text` widgets.

When I run the application I expect to see three vertically placed `Text` widgets on a white background screen, however, the screen is completely black.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

```
void main() {
  runApp(myCustomApp());
}

Widget myCustomApp() {
  return Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    child: Row(
      children: [
        Text(
          "Toolbar",
          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        ),
        Text(
          "Content",
          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        ),
        Text(
          "Bottom Nav",
          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I mixed the concepts of `Row` and `Columns`: to lay out a series of view vertically I need to use a `Column`, not a `Row`.

After fixing this, I had the issue that the text was not visible, this however, was because the `Text` color by default is white, and I specified the color of the `Container` also white.

Answer (score 0):

Since that widget is the root of your application, you should start by placing a `MaterialApp` and maybe a `Scaffold`.

Here's an example:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

/*Primo widget 'Radice' di tutta l'applicazione*/
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static GlobalKey<NavigatorState> mainNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body:Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  "Toolbar",
                  textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                ),
                Text(
                  "Content",
                  textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                ),
                Text(
                  "Bottom Nav",
                  textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct, that's what I would do in a production app, is that I was experimenting a bit and wanted to create my own version of `MaterialApp`, just for learning purposes...

Answer (score 0):

simple solution is that wrap your container with scaffold.